# How to query a dataset while calculating cumulative values (and filtering by thresholds)

Tags: google-sheets

I was hoping someone can help optimize this spreadsheet, where I need to QUERY a dataset while filtering by the cumulative sum of a column by certain thresholds.

Here's the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hC5qIkoOYIi19c_j2y3QztDLVo9gs4xnwglPFW_yQv4/edit?usp=sharing) if you want to take a look but I just want to incorporate the columns in yellow in the query, so I just have to use one formula. The query result would be only the rows where Column O "in threshold" is "Yes":
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Test File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m46JRHw8XpmqORy-tAsmxr4DXvmukUfLFB7juPwFaek/edit#gid=0)

Formula in *Q2* returns check to threshold conditions, also I separated those conditions in table in range S2:U4.

Formula calculates aggregate shares for current row

```
SUMIF(SEQUENCE(COUNT($M$2:$M),1,1,1),"<="&SEQUENCE(COUNT($M$2:$M),1,1,1),$M$2:$M)
```

and compares to threshold conditions table with VLOOKUP() formula.

Same repeats for previous row values.
Also there is additional check for cases when new country appears (second part of formula).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Oleg! Never thought about using SEQUENCE. Appreciate the help!